# Error:(24, 51) error: incompatible types: FragmentAcitvity cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-facebook

I am new in android programing. I want to add a facebook login page in my ting an error while adding a fragment in my main activity.

**Here is My Fragment Class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;



TextView textView;
private CallbackManager mcallbackManager;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback= new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken= loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile= Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if(profile != null){
            textView.setText("Welcome "+ profile.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    mcallbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("User_Friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(mcallbackManager, mCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

**Fragment XML Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mma.androidfacebook3.MyFrgment"

    >


    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity XML Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/main_layout">
```

**MainActivity class code**

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Fragment.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyFragment myfragment= new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_layout, myfragment, "dfs");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image: Error]
Error:(24, 51) error: incompatible types: MyFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

The minimum sdk viersion for this app is 9 and maximus sdk is 21.
It will be very helpfull if anyone suggest me how to solve this problem.
Thank You.

Comment: what is this `Fragment.`  you wrote just after the open curly bracket in your Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

in your MainActivity

Comment: Not in MainActivity he doesn't. Look carefully.

Comment: It is an unused import, It needs to be changed in the MyFragment class.